# validation on userid and password using ajax and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to know how to make validation on userId and password in asp.net application using ajax and jquery because i am new to ajax 
any help will be highly apperciated

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be have a server side script that takes `userid` and `password` parameters and verifies if they are valid.

Add Check.ashx generic handler to your project:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Check" %>

using System.Web;

public class Check : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var userid = context.Request["userid"];
        var password = context.Request["password"];

        string response = IsValid(userid, password) ? "true" : "false";
        context.Response.ContentType = "appliaction/json";
        context.Response.Write("{isvalid:'" + response + "'}");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string userid, string password)
    {
        return (userid == "john" && password == "secret");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

And then have your page send an ajax query.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a.check').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/check.ashx',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        userid: $('input[name=userid]').val(),
                        password: $('input[name=password]').val()
                    },
                    success: function(json) {
                        alert(json.isvalid);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        userid: <input type="text" name="userid" value="" />
        password: <input type="text" name="password" value="" />
        <a href="#" class="check">Check</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnx but i dont know jason and dont have enough time to learn ajax
simply
i have table in my data base
it's name is user
fields userID , password
and in my asp.net page
i have 2 textboxes and submit button
all i want to do is validation using ajax wether the user id and password are exist and right or not 
thnx for ur answers

Comment: If you don't have enough time to learn what exactly are you expecting or looking for? Someone do the work for you?

Comment: thnx darin for reply ,,i dont expect someone to do my work or something like that ,,all i want to use ajax in a specific task ,,and u answer me and thnx for that but and dont get ur answer well and i think it doesn't match with what i want,my application has a table named user in database and i use sqlserver2005
in this table there is 2 fields userId and password and i want to validate wether the password and userID are found and correct or not
using ajax,asp.net(c#) thats it,,thnx again

Answer (score 0):

well, ajax is basically the ability of calling webservices/wcf from the client (javascript), and you execute some webmethod with parameters, and receive some data, and that's kind off it

also you should not rely just on client validation because, the user can just disable javascript from his browser and all the ajax stuff/ javascript is not going to work

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should ask, I started this Blog post last night, no kidding!!!

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2009/11/11/Validating-A-Username-Using-JQuery-and-ASP.NET-Membership-Provider.aspx